# Name of note sequence present in many pop songs?

Tags: pop

I remember hearing about a 3 or 5 note sequence that is in many popular songs like Frozen's *Let it Go* or Katy Perry's *Fireworks.* Supposedly your brain eats it up like sugar.

Is there a name for what I am describing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an exact moment in a song that has that sequence? YouTube link with timestamp, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of the recently-named (and stupidly so) ["millenial whoop."](https://thepatterning.com/2016/08/20/the-millennial-whoop-a-glorious-obsession-with-the-melodic-alternation-between-the-fifth-and-the-third/) It's not a 3- or 5-note sequence, but rather an alternation between the 3rd and 5th notes of the scale.

([Here](http://qz.com/767812/millennial-whoop/) is a similar link.)

It's not a new thing; it's been in music for decades now. But some bozo must have decided that calling it "millenial" something would probably get more clicks.

Answer (score 3):

This is called an [earworm](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/music/earworm-catchy-tune-song-nursery-rhymes-god-save-the-queen-a7395911.html).  I'm not aware of one specific musical meme that dominates all others --if there was just one, I'm sure we'd all know it by heart --but the article referenced above describes some of the common characteristics of successful earworms.

The general idea of there being some particular musical figure of particular power is well-established in popular culture.  One example is the "secret chord" of Leonard Cohen's "Hallelujah" (really a progression, IV, V, vi, IV), and its predecessor, the "[Lost Chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Chord)".